# How to insert uneven data rows into matrix in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas, format

I have an originations data set with loan ids. I then have a corresponding dataset with performance data for each of these loans ids, which can be anywhere from 10-40 rows in the performance data set.

The start date of each of the performance loans is not the same either, although some do overlap. What I want to do is take every loan id group in the performance data set, and then create a row of a certain column value across all occurrences in the data set. It doesn't matter if they start on different dates, I just want to align the values as this is the first value for loan id x and y.

For example:

> ID   Date       Val
>
> 3    201601     100
>
> 3    201602     102
>
> 3    201603     103
>
> --> Result:
>
> ID  Val1   Val2   Val3
>
> 3   100   102   103

I'm having two issues. One is the differing size of performance data for each id. I can't construct a matrix with differing lengths of rows. I'm assuming I'll need to append 0's to the end of each row to meet a predefined width.

My second issue is that I'm not sure how to read through a the performance data set to group loans, extract the value column, construct the column into a row for that id, and then insert into a matrix. I know how I would do this in Python but I need to use SAS. I can construct tables in SAS, but I'm not sure how to append rows, only columns.

If someone could provide some guidance on this it'd be a great help.

Comment: This falls under a transpose. Because it's a SAS dataset and not a 'matrix' the idea of requiring the same number of rows/columns isn't valid. Look at proc transpose to reshape your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who runs into a similar issue it ended up being only a few lines of code.

```
proc transpose  data =  new_data
            out =  new_data1;
            var trans_state;
            by id;
run;
```

The output will be

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Reeza for the idea of proc transpose.